# I'm receiving an error on run

Tags: java

Okay so I've encountered an error and I'm not so sure why, any help would be appreciated. When I try run it, I'm met with the following.

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>       at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
>       at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
>       at JonesInc.main(JonesInc.java:16)

```
public class JonesInc
{
    public static void main(String[] args)   
   {
       Scanner kbReader=new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("1. Administration");
       System.out.println("2. Check Stock Availability");
       System.out.println("3. Purchase Textbooks");
       System.out.println("4. Return Textbooks");
       System.out.println("5. Quit");
       System.out.println("please select your choice");
       int choice=kbReader.nextInt();
       int stock=100;

       if(choice==1)
       {     
           Scanner password=new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Please Enter Password"); 
           String name=password.nextLine();

           if(name.equals("Java"))

                   System.out.println("A. Increase Stock Availabilty");
                   System.out.println("B. Reduce Stock Availability");
                   System.out.println("C. Quit"); 
                   System.out.println("Select your choice");
                   Scanner kbReader1=new Scanner(System.in); 
                   String choice1=kbReader1.nextLine();
                   char ch=choice1.charAt(0);
                   System.out.println("");

           switch (ch)
           {
               case'A':
               case'a':

                   System.out.println("How much do you wish to increase stock by");
                   break;

               case'B':
               case'b':

                   System.out.println("How much do you wish to decrease stock by");
                   break;

               case'C':
               case'c':

                   System.out.println("Dave is cool");
                   break;   
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to import your Scanner?

Comment: According to your indentation you're missing `{` and `}` after `if(name.equals("Java"))`.

Comment: you dont have to create a new scanner, every time you want to use one. Just reuse the previous one. And remember to close the scanner using `kbReader.close();`

Comment: It works for me too. How are you running the program and taking input? The answer by @UliKöhler seems to be a correct guess that you are running it in a way that doesn't have input to take.

Comment: For me it works (superficially at least, I didn't really test its algorithms) if running on NetBeans.

Comment: @steffen While I agree that is true logically, it is to my knowledge not related to the execution errors experienced by the OP.

Comment: @UliKöhler that's why i posted it as comment.

Answer (score 1):

You're running the program (which seems to work correctly, at least superficially) in some way which doesn't allow interactive input.

The `Scanner` tries to read here:

```
int choice=kbReader.nextInt();
```

but `System.in` is already closed.

You should run the program in a way that supports inputting data via `System.in`, e.g. in any major IDE.